# Excel return multiple values from numbered cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have the following problem, and would appreciate any help if it is even possible.

Given this Data on Sheet 1

```
Employee Role   Number of Employees  
Employee A              5  
Employee B              4  
Employee C              3
```

I would like the results to be this on Sheet 2.

Results

```
Employee A  
Employee A  
Employee A  
Employee A  
Employee A  
Employee B  
Employee B  
Employee B  
Employee B  
Employee C  
Employee C  
Employee C
```

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding info in comments.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and learn [ask]. Then edit your question and make it a good question before it gets closed. You show no effort of your own and this site is not a free script order service.

Comment: Sorry for the question appearing as though I showed no effort of research.  I did in fact try multiple things, and researched the question & restated it multiple ways.  However, I could not find anything close to what I was looking for, nor could I come up with anything on my own that was viable solution.  The best way I saw to expand the question was by example, but I should have provided more insight, and will be sure to do so in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not do this starting in cell `A1` in `Sheet2` because there would be a circular reference, and Excel gave me an error.
But if starting on cell `A2` is ok for you, here it is:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!$A$1:A1;Sheet1!$A$2)<Sheet1!$B$2;Sheet1!$A$2;IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!$A$1:A1;Sheet1!$A$3)<Sheet1!$B$3;Sheet1!$A$3;IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!$A$1:A1;Sheet1!$A$4)<Sheet1!$B$4;Sheet1!$A$4;"")))
```

Just put this formula on cell `A2` of `Sheet2` and drag down.

I've tested and the result was the one you're excpecting.

Comment: I edited my initial post, sorry for the extra comment.  Your solution works if I have the results already in the cell.  Sorry for the confusion, but maybe I should have labeled that as expected results.  The results column in sheet 2 is what I need the formula to produce.

Comment: But that's exactly what it is. My formula is meant to be put in Sheet2, so that it uses data from Sheet1 to produce the result you're expecting.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, I either read or copied something incorrectly.  This works, thank you so much for your time & effort!